# Cowsay vim commands instead of fortune

Tags: bash, vim

I followed [tutorial](http://lmpeiris.wordpress.com/2011/01/17/cowsayhow-to-make-a-cow-talk-on-terminal-startup/) to install cowsays with fortune texts...

But I am wondering is there something for vim commands ?

I want to be able on every loggin to my bash so see some vim command...

Comment: Do you mean "the doc for a Vim command"?

Comment: well could be anything... for example one message could be "+n file Meaning Open file at line number n."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need the tips, look no further than [here](http://rayninfo.co.uk/vimtips.html).

To show up these when you **launch Vim** (I don't know whether showing on Bash startup makes that much sense, as you cannot try out the tip immediately), a quick search yields

- [Random Tip Displayer plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1811)
- [vimfortune plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=298)

(There are probably more.)